# Another Moderator Question Regarding Flagging Old Questions

Tags: discussion, moderators

Sorry but I'm sure this has been asked before but I couldn't find it...

Again its related to old questions that are unanswered, I've found a few questions such as

I have this problem blah blah blah, and then in comment they say never mind its fixed now, or I did this and it sorted the problem. Some of these are donkeys old and should be marked answered but due to the fact they are either in the comment, or they don't answer there own question it remains open. Whats the best course of action on these types of questions with comments.

Comment: For maximum irony, the answer to this question should be posted as a comment. (Good question, bybe, can comments be promoted to answers? Can we re-answer the question with essentially the same answer as the comment?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the answer is in the comments then this question on meta.stackoverflow.com covers it: [Should old questions with a solution in the comments but no posted answer be answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139075/should-old-questions-with-a-solution-in-the-comments-but-no-posted-answer-be-ans).

If they say it's fixed, and it looks like it's going to very specific for them then and there's no solution in the question, then flag for close - "too localised".

If someone answers an old question then even though the original questioner may not benefit, the rest of us may.